# SetTimeOut в цикле для массива

Tags: javascript

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает код.
Пользователь вводит в input строку с числами через запятую, например "2,5,7", строка преобразуется в массив чисел. Полоса прогресс-бара до полной загрузки должна сдвинуться ровно столько раз, сколько чисел в массиве ("2,5,7" - этом примере 3 раза). При этом задерживаться на указанное число секунд, т.е. сначала на 2, потом на 5 и на 7(числа будут зависеть от того, что ввел пользователь).
Функция moveProgressBar вроде как срабатывает правильно. Значит главная проблема заключается в setTimeout:

```
       let width = 0;

        btn.addEventListener ("click", function getInterval() {

            let delaysArr = input.value.split(",");

            for (let delay of delaysArr){

                let id = setTimeout(moveProgressBar, delay*1000); 

                function moveProgressBar() {
                    if (width >= 100) {
                     clearTimeout(id);
                  } else {   
                     width += 100/delaysArr.length;
                     greenProgressBar.style.width = width + '%'
                     counter.innerHTML = width.toFixed(2) * 1  + '%';
                 }}}})
```

Пробовала читать проблемы у других на эту тему, но так не поняла, что конкретно нужно исправить у меня в коде. По другому примеру сделала второй вариант кода, но он тоже не работает:

```
        let width = 0;
        let delaysArr = [];

        function getInterval(array, delegate, delay) {
                
                array.forEach(function (el) {
                    
                    setTimeout(()=>{delegate();}, el * delay);
                })
        }

        btn.addEventListener ("click", ()=>{
            
            delaysArr = input.value.split(",");
            
            getInterval(delaysArr,
            function () {   

                 width += 100/delaysArr.length;
                 greenProgressBar.style.width = width + '%'
                 counter.innerHTML = width.toFixed(2) * 1  + '%';

            }, 1000)})
```

Вот ссылка на полный код: https://codepen.io/Kalskaya/pen/PoQPqEz;
Знаю, что главная проблема, что setTimeOut находится в цикле, не знаю, что именно исправить. Скорее всего вопрос глупый, но уже целый день не могу найти правильное решение, поэтому прошу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то основная проблема была в том, что страница перезагружалась, а так я сделал небольшой рефакторинг, логику почти не менял:

```js
const greenProgressBar = document.getElementById('greenProgressBar');
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
const btn = document.getElementById('start');
const input = document.getElementById('delays');
const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault()); //Чтобы страница не перезагружалась

let width = 0;

const moveProgressBar = (parts) => {
  width += 100 / parts;
  
  if (width > 100) width = 100;
  
  greenProgressBar.style.width = width + "%";
  counter.innerHTML = width.toFixed(2) + "%";
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const delaysArr = input.value.split(',').map(x => Number(x.trim()));

  for (const delay of delaysArr) {
    setTimeout(() => {moveProgressBar(delaysArr.length)}, delay * 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
#greyProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#greenProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

#counter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="delays" style="color:red">Set delays list:</label>
  <input id="delays" type="text">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<div id="greyProgressBar">
  <p id="counter">0%</p>
  <div id="greenProgressBar"></div>
</div>
```